# What is the problem when i want to install cv2 in pycharm?

Tags: python

```
collecting cv2

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: First of all, show us the exact command you used to try to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install opencv-python`,
and also to upgrade the
pip command with
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`